# Android studio shows can not find Declaration to go to in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

while working on a flutter project, Android studio behaving strangely for some of the dart files is shows **Cannot find declaration to go to**  even for BuildContext.  ( Project runs without any errors )

issue snapshot:

[image]

while some of the dart files in the same project are able to go to the declarations and find the references.

I have already tried the following methods:

- Invalidate cache and restart
- deleted .idea folder
- updated flutter plugin

None of the above methods worked for me, Is there any way to resolve this error? any suggestions or solutions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue just by deleting the `@override` and writing it again..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error ... the code compiled cleanly, and ran, but I was not able to go to the declaration for any properties or classes, etc. I noticed that the code folding indicators weren't showing after a certain point in the file, so I think Visual Studio is getting confused. In my case, I moved a static method from the start of the class to the end, and this resolved all of the problems except for references within that static method. I'm using Android Studio Flamingo/2022.2.1 Patch 2 (built on May 12, 2023).